# Can't start new activity in android app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I start a new activity by taking a picture and passing its data to the activity.
For some reason the activity dosen't start. (or maybe it take a lot of time)
Like this:

```
        cameraResult = new Intent(Activity.this, ResultActivity.class);

        final Camera.PictureCallback cameraSavePictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cameraResult.putExtra("PictureData", data);
            cameraResult.putExtra("size", "10cm");
            startActivity(cameraResult);
        }
    };

    final ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    final Camera.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, cameraSavePictureCallback);                
        }
    });
```

I have a break point in the new activity and it dosen't get their, So the problem is not in the activity.

Can someone tell me what could be wrong and if this is the proper way to show the picture in a new screen?

**EDIT1:**  I forgot to mention that this happens only when I take a picture that are not black at all. I mean, if I cover the lens and take a picture it dosen't stuck

**EDIT2:** I have an error in the logcat

```
04-13 14:09:34.777: ERROR/JavaBinder(13009): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: put your break point in onPictureTaken and  check whats going on there.

Comment: In onPictureTaken everything goes well it exits the function and then it stuck.

Comment: are there any errors in LogCat?

Comment: Yes. I added them to the quetion

Comment: Eventually I found an answer here:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7322a84adcfee567

Answer (score 0):

dude change to
        final Camera.PictureCallback cameraSavePictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cameraResult = new Intent(Activity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        cameraResult.putExtra("PictureData", data);
        cameraResult.putExtra("size", "10cm");
        startActivity(cameraResult);
    }
};
```

Comment: why do I need to change this?